# Monkeypatching from a Sinatra helper

Tags: ruby, sinatra, monkeypatching

I've defined a Sinatra helper in the usual way:

```
module Sinatra
  module FooHelper
    # code goes here
  end
end
```

In my helper, among other things, I'd like to add a method to `Numeric`:

```
module Sinatra
  module FooHelper
    class ::Numeric
      def my_new_method
      end
    end
  end
end
```

However, in the interests of being unobtrusive, I only want to do add this method if my Sinatra helper is actually included in an application; if nobody runs `helpers Sinatra::FooHelper`, I don't want to affect anything (which seems like a reasonable thing to expect of a Sinatra extension).

Is there any hook that's fired when my helper is included, that would enable me to add my method only once that happens?

Comment: Would someone `require` this and then not use it?

Comment: @iain it's possible that they could include it in one part of a modular Sinatra app, but not in another — I realise it's not exactly the most likely thing in the world, but I'd like to write as clean an extension as possible/practical.

Comment: If you're going to go to that extent then I'd say why not use a class method instead? No patching, can return the same type, easy to understand, ultimately far, far cleaner. Bit more ugly though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Module#included` method to do this. I think you will need to modify your class definition slightly to use `class_eval`. I've tested the following and it works as expected:

```
module Sinatra
  module FooHelper    
    def self.included(mod)
      ::Numeric.class_eval do
        def my_new_method
          return "whatever"
        end
      end
    end
  end  
end
```